# How to define device label name, g_mass_storage module

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, usb-mass-storage, removable-storage

Working on an embedded system which includes g_mass_storage module in its Kernel configuration, I would like to define the device's name. This latter will be usefull in order to identify the device when plugged to an host.

I am using the following function :

```
int usb_gadget(void) 
{
    char cmd[512];
    int  fd = -1;
    int  len = -1;

    memset((void *)cmd, 0x00, sizeof(cmd));

    fd = open("proc/modules", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd > 0) 
    {
        len = read(fd, cmd, sizeof(cmd));
        if (len > 0) 
        {
            if (strstr(cmd, "g_mass_storage") > 0) 
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Missing module \n");   
            } 
            else 
            {
                strcpy(cmd, "modprobe ");
                strcat(cmd, "g_mass_storage");
                strcat(cmd, " file=");
                strcat(cmd, "tmp/testfile");
                strcat(cmd," idVendor=2000 ");
                strcat(cmd," idProduct=2000 ");
                strcat(cmd," bcdDevice=2000 ");
                strcat(cmd," iManufacturer=TEST ");
                strcat(cmd," iProduct=BOARD1 ");
                strcat(cmd," iSerialNumber=1 ");                    
                system(cmd);
            }
            close(fd);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When the device is connected to a Windows PC, the device is defined as `Local Disk(E:)`.

How to exchange `Local Disk` by a specific name as it is done for my USB Key `SnPKey` ?

EDIT 1 :

[Mass Storage Gadget](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt)

According to the information given in the previous link, I tried to specify an USB Product string thru `iProduct` without success.

Comment: After many researches, this write seems to be realized during the partitionning step. I will realize a test on the platform soon.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found.

The volume label must be defined during the sectors creation.

In my case, I validated the process by writting `0x4E,0x4F,0x20,0x4E,0x41,0x4D,0x45,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20` which is equals to `NO NAME`.